# gcc compiler optimization - influence on assembly

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I am learning about gcc optimization. As far as I understand the compilers tries to improve/ reduce the code.

That is noticeable when I execute different files with different optimization levels. Adding `-O3` during compiling I get the fastest result when I run the compiled program.

As it has been improved, I thought the assembly files must have less commands. However, when looking into that files I saw that it has even more than the default one.

- Is it true that the assembly file will have more commands, nevertheless it is running faster than the other one? If yes, how is that possible? What has been improved?
- What is the general influence on assembly / object files when using optimization flags in gcc?

Comment: The second question is interesting but too broad for Stackoverflow as it's not a simple answerable question that is suitable for the SO format. And the answer to the first question is yes, of course. In fact, trading space for speed is a common computing tradeoff. For starters, read the [gcc manual optimsations section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) which summarises the optimisations options  which will or will not affect code size.

Comment: @kaylum in fact, most of making a compiler generate good code is about finding the right space/speed tradeoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler optimizations may frequently cause the *number* of instructions to increase, in order for execution time to decrease. For example, if the compiler sees that a for-loop will always loop exactly N times, it may choose to generate N copies of the loop body, thereby avoiding jump/comparison instructions.

You can tell the compiler to optimize for size (e.g. `-Os`), in which case it will try really hard not to increase the number of instructions, sometimes at the expense of a slower program. This is very common in embedded applications where the amount of RAM is the most constraining factor.

Running e.g. gcc with `-O2` will cause the compiler to try to balance the code to be as fast as possible, while not growing too much in size. Exact how this affects the assembler/object files is very complicated. If you want to know more, there are lots of online courses covering compiler construction and optimizations.

Comment: Thank you @JesperE Great answer!!

Comment: Your first example was great... that's why I accepted your answer. I found exact what your described in my assembly, thanks!!